# fetch store data in ngrx selector

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-selectors

say in my store I have a feature with an array of data and an index

```
{
    data: Data[],
    activeIndex: -1
}
```

What I want to do is, every time `activeIndex` changes, I get notified and get `data[activeIndex]`

so I have a selector

```
const selectActiveIndex = creatSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (feature) => feature.activeIndex
)
```

But how do I get `data[activeIndex]` in my component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a selector based on other selectors, here you can combine the results into a single result. This combined selector can then be used in the component.

```
const selectActiveIndex = creatSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (feature) => feature.activeIndex
)

const selectData = creatSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (feature) => feature.data
)

const selectActiveData = createSelector(
  selectActiveIndex,
  selectData,
  (idx, data) => data[idx]
)
```

component:

```
activeData$ = this.store.select(selectActiveData)

constructor(private store:Store)
```

Comment: Hi, I think this `selectActiveData` selector will be updated every time feature.data or index change, but actually, I only want to subscribe to index change. The silly solution is to query the store for the data when index change. Just not sure if there's a smater way